# exception generated inside an await block is not catched in try catch block

Tags: c#, exception, asynchronous, try-catch, async-await

I have a sync function such as the following function that generate an IO error (I delete the detail to make it simple):

```
public override void SyncFunction()
{
   throw new IOException("test");
}
```

and I used it in this way:

```
try
{
    await Task.Run(() => this.SyncFunction());
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error:"+Environment.NewLine + ex.Message);
}
```

But when I run the application, the catch block doesn't get called, but I am getting a message that application crashed. What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: I doubt that's actually the code. This code should handle the exception.

Answer (score 2):

The code as you described it should handle the exception just fine.

However, the thing that **would** crash your application is an exception thrown inside an `async void` method as the exception has no `Task` to be stored inside.

So, my guess is that `SyncFunction` actually looks more like this:

```
public override async void SyncFunction()
{
    throw new IOException("test");
}
```

And when you invoke it the exception is posted to a `ThreadPool` thread and that crashes the application.

If that's the case, don't use `async void` unless in a UI event handler and make sure you handle such exceptions by registering to the `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event.

Comment: SyncFunction is part of an interface, can I decorate it with async without breaking interface integrity?

Comment: @mans yes. `async` is an implementation detail for a method. But remember, the point is to **not** use `async void`